# Edit a list of many elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have like 100 (or more) elements in a list which is very similar to this:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'mysite.it/ajax/list_filter.php',
        data:data,
        type:'POST'
    }).done(function(data){
        var reback = $.parseJSON(data);
        var people = '';
        if(reback.success){ 
            if(reback.showcase){
                $.each((reback.showcase),function(index,item){
                    var exists = $('ul#ul_people_list input[value="'+item.userid+'"]');
                    if(exists){
                        exists.parent('li').remove();
                    }
                    people += '<li>';
                    people += '<input type="hidden" class="username" name="username" value="' + item.userid + '"/>';
                    people += '<a class="show_dtl';
                    if(item.vip != 0){people += ' vip ';}
                    people += '" href="usr_dtl">';
                    people += '<div><img src="'mysite.it/pict_thumbs/' +item.pool_user_pict+ '" style="height: 80px; left: 1px;"></div>';
                    people += '<label>' +item.username+ '</label>';
                    if(item.vip != 0){people += '<span class="icon-star"></span>';}
                    people += '</a></li>';
                });

                if(refreshType == 2){//if refreshing
                    $('#people_list ul#ul_people_list').prepend(people);
                } else {
                    $('#people_list ul#ul_people_list').html(people);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $('#people_list ul#ul_people_list').html('<li>' + reback.showcase + '</li>');}
    });
```

When I refresh the list (about every 20 seconds) I have to add some element, update some element and delete some element.
I do all this with jQuery.
What is the best way, performance-wise, to do it?
At the moment I use the value attribute (in the second input element) to address the element I want to edit.
Is it better if I change my code to:
`<li id="/* userid */">`
Of course other suggestions are appreciated?

Comment: What do you have so far for the jquery part?

Comment: At the moment I haven't anything, I am just thinking of using the value attribute to address the element, and then by traversing the DOM I edit what I need.

Comment: I would suggest going ahead and coding out an example of what you just said. Then paste it in here for others to work with. It's hard to start with nothing and tell you how to do it. That's more of a job for a tuturial, not a question/answer site.

Comment: not really clear what your higher level issue is. If it's already updating every 20 seconds how is that being done?

Comment: Manipulate elements with jquery and ajax, each 20 seconds get new json with changes you need to apply, not with all elements data (do not duplicate). Since your list element is a wrapper, apply `data-id="YOURID"` on it.

Comment: This Ajax request is done every 20 seconds. This makes the search:         var exists = $('ul#ul_people_list input[value="'+item.userid+'"]');    Is it better to search this way or through $('ul#ul_people_list li#' +item.userid); or through data-id as @skobaljic said?

Comment: You will change several elements there, it is best to select their container first.

Comment: You mean it's best select the li element by its id?